# How to typecast a HashMap to a WeakHashMap?

Tags: java

I have a method like this :-

```
public Map<String,String> loadProperties() Exception{
    Map <String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
.
.
.
  return params;
}
```

The above method returns me a Map of (key , value) from the DB.

I need to TypeCast loadProperties() to a WeakHashMap. Below I have another class called Service. I tried the typecasting in its constructor but it is giving me ClassCastException.

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.WeakHashMap"
```

Below is the Service class:-

```
private Service() throws Exception {
   configPropertiesCache = dao.loadProperties();
 configPropertiesCache = (WeakHashMap<String, String>) dao.loadProperties();
```

I am curious to know why its not working ?

Comment: Type casting != conversion for objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because a `HashMap` simply is not a `WeakHashMap`. Type casting does not do any kind of magical conversion from one type to another type.

The only thing that a type cast means is that you tell the compiler that you want it to treat one type of object as if it is another type of object - but a check will still be done at runtime to check if the object you're casting really is what you cast it to, and if the check fails you get a `ClassCastException`.

Either create the map as a `WeakHashMap` in your `loadProperties()` method, or if you cannot modify that method, copy it into a `WeakHashMap`:

```
configPropertiesCache = new WeakHashMap<>(dao.loadProperties());
```

Answer (score 2):

do it like this:

```
public WeakHashMap<String, String> getWeakHashMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    if (map instanceof WeakHashMap) {
        return (WeakHashMap<String,String>) map;
    }
    return new WeakHashMap<String,String>(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` isn't a `WeakHashMap` so you **cant cast one to the other**. However, you can return `WeakHashMap` in your `loadProperties` method, or convert the `HashMap` to a `WeakHashMap` manually.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap and WeakHashMap are different Map implementations, and as such you can't cast one to the other.  In general, if you have ClassA with subclasses ClassB and ClassC, then you can cast ClassB or ClassC to ClassA, but you cannot cast ClassB to ClassC or vice versa.

If you want to turn HashMap into a WeakHashMap then you'll need to create a new WeakHashMap, then iterate through your HashMap and add all of its key-value pairs to the WeakHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

The type cast won't work but you could create an `asWeakHashMap` method that takes a map and adds all the entries into a new `WeakHashMap` and returns that map.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a `Map` to a `WeakHashMap` but you can create a new `WeakWashMap` which contains all values. You can do it with that code:

```
Map<String, String> otherMap = new HashMap()<String, String>;
map.put("Hello", "World");
WeakHashMap<String, String> weakMap = new WeakHashMap(otherMap);
System.out.println(weakMap.get("Hello"));
```